# unique X500 Object Id not being generated, while creating new Attribute in AD schema

Tags: active-directory

We am trying to extend the ActiveDirectory Schema to add a couple of variables. When I create an attribute in ADSchema Editor, the unique X500 Object Id is not being generated by default. 
How to resolve this issue ? With out this unique identifier, we cannot create new attributes in AD.
Logged in as Administrator, Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for my confusion. Looks like Unique X500 Object never gets auto-generated in AD when creating new attribute. (even though i have a strange feeling that I have seen this in the past). Either way, the below links gives elaborate explanation of what an unique X500 Object is & how we can obtain a new one, so this answers my question.

**Obtaining an Object Identifier from Microsoft**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677620.aspx